# Does this sequences convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Consider the space $X=[0,1)$. and consider the sequence

$\{x_n\}=\{1-\frac 12, \frac 12,1-\frac 13, \frac 13,1-\frac 14,\frac 14, 1-\frac 15,\frac 15 ,\cdots\}$.

Is this sequence convergent ?

Here $\{x_n\}$ has two subsequences $\{\frac 1n\}$ and $\{1-\frac 1n\}$ converges to $0\in X$ and $1\not \in X$ respectively. What can we say about convergence of $\{x_n\}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider it  as a sequence  in $\mathbb R$. If a sequence converges all subsequences have to converge to its limit. So $(x_n)$ is not convergent in $\mathbb R$ and hence it cannot converge in $[0,1)$.